# Ambiguous assembly binding policies

Tags: postsharp

Recently we've encountered the following exception when building one of our projects.

Why does Postsharp complain about the binding as the bindings are (visually) the same?

Whe have tried to upgrade to 5.0.51 (Essentials), but due to licensing we can't upgrade.

Regards,
Guido Hermans

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unhandled exception (4.1.15.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.461808, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Ambiguous assembly binding policies: Assembly 'newtonsoft.json, version=9.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' redirects both to 'newtonsoft.json, version=9.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'newtonsoft.json, version=9.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyBindingPolicyManager.EvaluatePolicy(IAssemblyName assemblyName, Boolean evaluateSystemPolicies)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.^4+F3cylo(IAssemblyName _0, IAssemblyName _1, AssemblyBindingPolicyManager _2, BindingOptions _3, Boolean _4)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.^nQbUijLO(String _0, IAssemblyName _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindType(Type reflectionType, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.DisableMessagesTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation). .......
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you don't have two assembly binding redirections in configuration files. PostSharp in that version most likely doesn't take into account that both redirections may point to the same assembly name.

Comment: @DanielBalas How can I verify that? I've redirected PostSharp to the web.config via the <PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>True</PostSharpHostConfigurationFile> setting. What else can I check?

Comment: Never mind.
It turned out the tag below had a duplicate in the web.config.
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>

Comment: @GuidoHermans, you can post your last comment as an answer